# How to remove item from Pill Container?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a Pill Container, which contains items from the Contact sObject.
When I click the x button nothing happens.

CMP:

```
<lightning:pillContainer items="{!v.selectedContactList}" onitemremove="handleRemovePill"/>
```

My Contact List is dynamically selected, so it could be changed anytime.

---

I also tried to build the container and the items in a loop

```
<span>
    <aura:iteration var="pillLabel" items="{!v.selectedContactList}">
        <span class="slds-pill">{!pillLabel.Name}
            <button onclick="{!c.handleRemovePill}" class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-pill__remove" title="Remove">
                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="x-small" class="slds-input__icon" alternativeText="Remove" />
            </button>
        </span>
    </aura:iteration>
</span>
```

When I click the x button it reacts, but I don't know how to get the actual record.

Comment: Looks like you're calling the action method in the wrong way. You missed the `{!c.}`. You should try: `<lightning:pillContainer items="{!v.selectedContactList}" onitemremove="{!c.handleRemovePill}"/>`. Also, we can't help you if you don't post the controller method.

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem! how couldn’t I notice this!

Comment: You're welcome ! It happened to all of us at least once!